# Accessing variables that are defined in a document ready closure in the bodytag

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I want to access variables through the console that are within `$(function(){});` that resides before the body closing tag.
I already learned that vars inside this closure are not accessible but people are talking about setting breakpoints in the developer tools.
From what I can see I can only set breakpoints in the sources (linked javascript) and really haven't any clue on how to set a breakpoint in this particular situation.

Is it possible at all?

```
$(function() {

  var model = {
    somevar: []
  };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting a breakpoint in Chrome browser:

- Click the Sources tab.
- Open the file containing the line of code you want to break on.
- Go the line of code.
- To the left of the line of code is the line number column. Click on
  it. A blue icon appears on top of the line number column.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for now, for you, it would be to add `debugger;` in your javascript code where ever you want to study the  script. Then load the page with the `console` open and you will see that the execution will stop on these `debugger;` places and you will be able to watch the values of various variables, even in anonymous contexts.

Also I would read this [using the console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/)

Comment: I don't have control over the code so i can't set thing prior to execution. @bluehipy

Comment: Still source is editable in browser console. You can visit the Source tab , choose your script, add `debugger`; mention where eveer you want. Or just set breakpoints by clicking on the left side, on the line numbers. Read the article I have recommended, it will help!

Comment: Ok i'll read it but it's clear to you that the script resides in the html page? It is not a linked .js.

Comment: Doesn't matter where the script is. You can set breakpoints where ever the code is and you can edit it as well, on your local copy.